# Forwarding all iMessages to email using AppleScript

Tags: email, applescript, attachment, forward, imessage

I'm new to AppleScript but learned a bit from searching online. Basically I would like to forward iMessage messages to an e-mail address. I did this with the following script:

```
using terms from application "Messages"
    on message received theMessage from theBuddy for theChat

        tell application "Mail"
            set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"thesubject", content:theMessage, visible:true}
            tell theNewMessage
                make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"myemail@gmail.com"}
                send
            end tell
        end tell

    end message received
end using terms from
```

Works great and it puts the iMessage in the content of an e-mail that gets sent to me.

Now I'm trying to do this with attachments as well. I modified the code to give me 4 beeps when a file is received but nothing happens. Posted this question to Apple's website but then I thought I would have better luck here. Any help would really be appreciated I've searched google for hours and I'm kind of at a dead end.

Modified Code:

```
using terms from application "Messages"
    on message received theMessage from theBuddy for theChat

        tell application "Mail"
            set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties    
                {subject:"thesubject", content:theMessage, visible:true}
            tell theNewMessage
                make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties  
                     {address:"myemail@gmail.com"}
                send
            end tell
         end tell

    end message received
    on completed file transfer theFile
        beep 4

    end completed file transfer
end using terms from
```

So with a bit more looking I learned that Messages is very similar to iChat which I found some example code on Apple's Developer site:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/iChatAppleScriptSamples/Listings/Add_Incoming_Images_to_iPhoto_Add_incoming_image_to_iPhoto_applescript.html

So I changed my code to this:

```
on received file transfer invitation theFileTransfer
    accept transfer of theFileTransfer
    tell application "Mail"
        set theNewMessage to make new outgoing message with properties
            {subject:"photo", content:"themessage", visible:true}
        tell theNewMessage
            make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties
                {address:"myemail@gmail.com"}
            send
        end tell
    end tell
end received file transfer invitation
```

I also made sure to have the script run when incoming file in the Messages preferences window, but still not getting any response. Very frustrating, I'm thinking that a picture might not be a file transfer but rather an inline text attachment of sorts.

Looking at the Messages dictionary I found:

**attachment** n [inh. rich text] : Represents an inline text attachment. This class is used mainly for make commands.
elements
contained by rich text, characters, paragraphs, words, attribute runs.
properties
file (file, r/o) : The path to the file for the attachment  syn file name

But I have no idea how to use classes in AppleScript.
Again any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not on my Mac right now so I can't take a look in the AS Libraries to do the research I should before answering this question. It looks like `theMessage` in your earlier code is a string. If you could find a way to get the actual message object then you can use `get attachment of message_object` and I'm sure there is some other method in the Library that would allow you to check if there is an attachment before running that code.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been in AppleScript hell for the past few days. Apparently, when Apple changed how `Messages.app` deals with events (one event handler instead of a script per event), they either broke or failed to implement `file transfer`-related stuff.

Attachments are not accessible because you are never given a file object; rather (you’ve discovered) you get a message *string* and user and chat *objects*.

There’s good news in all of this, though (kind of). `on message received` is triggered for text messages *and* media messages. For media messages, the text string your handler gets is empty. You can hit up `last file transfer` to see if anything was recently received and act accordingly.

Here’s the nasty hack I’m using in the `message received` handler to get attachments:

```
set fileName to ""
if direction of last file transfer is incoming then
    -- compare diff in seconds
    if (current date) - (started of last file transfer) < 5 then
        set f to file of the last file transfer
        set fileName to POSIX path of f
    end if
end if
```

Do note that it’s only the start of an idea. I haven’t had time to improve it since I banged it out a few days ago. You’ll get the full path to the file in `fileName` if the message has media.

For the `Mail.app` side of things, basically, I have no clue. To send images with `Messages.app`, I’m using `set theMessage to POSIX file fileName`. Probably something along those lines for setting the `file` for `attachment`.

AppleScript is like messed up English, which is why you can use `first` and `last` and `2nd` and even `1th` or `3nd`. You can do stuff like `get number of file transfers` but `get number of file transfer` is also valid.

Partially related: checkout out `properties` if you ever want to inspect an object. `properties` plus the AppleScript Editor (as in `get properties of first chat`) are a lifesaver.

Good luck.